# Replace tree view "create" and "import" button with other button

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-9

i am working on a project in odoo 9. I need to replace "create" buttons, i tries that code but on module upgrade it gives error

I tries to use that code

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="oeh_lab_test_report_tree">
            <field name="name">Lab Tests Report</field>
            <field name="model">oeh.medical.lab.test</field>
            <field name="type">tree</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//page[@string='Create']" position="attributes">
                    <button string="Some Button" class="oe_highlight" type="button"/>
                </xpath>
                <tree string='Group Lab Tests'>
                    <field name="name"/>
                    <field name="patient"/>
                    <field name="test_type"/>
                    <field name="date_requested"/>
                    <field name="date_analysis"/>
                    <field name="state"/>
                    <button type="object" name="test_results_download" string="Download Test Results" class="oe_highlight"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>
```

when i upgrade my module it throws an error which is

```
View inheritance may not use attribute 'string' as a selector.
```

Answer (score 1):

1st: you are setting a `button` as an attribute and that's wrong.

2nd: looks like using the `string` attribute is not working anymore in v9. Have a look at this issue https://github.com/OCA/maintainer-quality-tools/issues/262.

So, you have a bunch of options:

1. select the page via position
2. ask the author to give a name or id to the page
3. do the above yourself and submit a pull request

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Could you please help my by code, am badly stuck in it

Comment: I tried using "inside" but still it is give error which is "View inheritance may not use attribute 'string' as a selector.", and i think odoo 9 do not support string selection

Comment: you are right, sound like this is not working anymore in v9. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Odoo 9 do not support string selection. Use @name